# Connect by in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-query

Suppose that we have following tables

```
create table Employee(
  2    EMPNO         NUMBER(3),
  3    ENAME         VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
  4    HIREDATE      DATE,
  5    ORIG_SALARY   NUMBER(6),
  6    CURR_SALARY   NUMBER(6),
  7    REGION        VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  8    MANAGER_ID    NUMBER(3)
  9  )
```

and

```
create table job (
  2    EMPNO         NUMBER(3),
  3    jobtitle      VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
  4  )
  5  /
```

I am interested in what the below query does

```
SELECT empno, manager_id, ename
  2  FROM employee
  3  START WITH empno = 1
  4  CONNECT BY PRIOR empno = manager_id;
```

As I understood this code selects `empno`,`manager_id`,`ename` from employee, it starts selection from this row where `empno=1`, but could not understand what this line does:

```
CONNECT BY PRIOR empno = manager_id;
```

Is this the same as:

```
where empno=manager_id?
```

Comment: [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
CONNECT BY PRIOR empno = manager_id;
```

This will produce the recursion. All records that are part of the next lower hierarchical level will return. This will return a hierarchy from top to bottom for all managers and their respective under working subordinates.

```
30 (manager_id)
   12 
   5 (manager_id)
      1
      7
20 (manager_id)
   15
   10
```

Comment: so how  can i guess if i need  code like this  to select something?

Comment: Simply when ever you want to get something which has parent-child relation in hierarchical manner.

Answer (score 6):

The query is recursive, it start from employee #1 (CEO probably) and then recursively prints all his subordinates and then all their subordinates  and so on and so forth (until all the employees are printed).

A good explanation about the "START WITH" and "CONNECT BY" can be found [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html)